# How to do an Unsub event on a shared publication list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working on a landing page, and right now, the code is all done in AMPScript (as that's what I'm most comfortable with).  I have a one-click unsub page that is working great, except for cases where the email was sent to a publication list that was a shared publication list. I already have a method to determine that

1. The list is a publication list
2. The list is top-level/ent

**Existing code**:

```
SET @ll_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"EmailAddress", @SubscriberKey)
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)

set @subscription = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "ID",@ListID)
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "IDSpecified", "true")
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "Status", "Unsubscribed" )
SetObjectProperty( @subscription, "StatusSpecified", "true" )     
AddObjectArrayItem( @ll_sub, "Lists", @subscription )

SET @ll_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @ll_statusMsg, @errorCode)
```

I have a @Flag variable that tells me if it is enterprise level or not, and I have a @Type variable that tells me if this is a group, list, or publication list.

*Any thoughts on how to log an unsub event to this publication list when it is top level?*

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the parent BU MID in the `SetObjectProperty` and use a `SimpleFilterPart` for the Publication List ID:

```
SET @MID = "Account MID Here"
SET @clientID = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@clientID, "ID", @MID)

set @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"Property","ListID")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp,"Value","Publication ListID Here")
```